# Conditional probability and intersections of events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

Conditional probability is : $$P(A\mid B)= \frac{P\left(A \bigcap B\right)}{P(B)}$$
Why did I find this as a solution of an exercise :
$$P\left(\left(E_1 \bigcap E_2 \bigcap E_3\right)\mid H\right) = P\left(E_1\mid H\right) \cdot P\left(E_2\mid \left(E_1 \bigcap H\right)\right) \cdot P\left(E_3\mid \left(E_1 \bigcap E_2 \bigcap H\right)\right)$$
I have two questions :

1. where's the P(B) of the definition in the denominator?
2. how do I go ahead when I have an intersection of more than 1 event given an event in the conditional probability?

Comment: That formula should make intuitive sense if you think through what it means. David already gave the formal derivation.

Answer (score 3):

$$\eqalign{{\rm RHS}
  &=\frac{P(E_1\cap H)}{P(H)}\,\frac{P(E_2\cap E_1\cap H)}{P(E_1\cap H)}\,
    \frac{P(E_3\cap E_1\cap E_2\cap H)}{P(E_1\cap E_2\cap H)}\cr
  &=\frac{P(E_1\cap E_2\cap E_3\cap H)}{P(H)}\cr
  &={\rm LHS}\ .\cr}$$

Comment: What do you mean with "RHS" and "LHS"?

Comment: Right/left hand side.  Of the equation.

Comment: If I have an intersection of two or more events  P(E1∩H)/P(H) in the numerator or in the denominator can I solve it with a moltiplication EX: P(E1) x P(E2) x P(H)  or should I  go ahead with inverse formula of conditional probability ?

Comment: You can multiply if the events are [independent](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=probability+independent+events).

Comment: Is there a way to know if two events are independent without using conditional probability formula?

Comment: It's generally accepted that if two events are "physically independent" (e.g. throwing two different dice) then it's reasonable to assume they are probabilistically independent.  Otherwise I should think you have to use the conditional or other equivalent formula.